# What is the best way to load polyfills for custom elements?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, polyfills, custom-element

I'm currently playing around with custom elements. I'm struggling to find the correct way (or what feels like the correct way) to polyfill browser who lack support (seemingly only Firefox?).

I'm currently doing the following:

```
if ('customElements' in window) {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = '/static/elements/my-element.js';
    document.body.appendChild(e);   
} else {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    // customElements
    e.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/1.0.8/webcomponents-sd-ce.js';
    e.onload = function() {
        var c = document.createElement('script');
        // ShadyCSS
        c.src = '/static/js/custom-style-interface.min.js';
        c.onload = function() {
            var i = document.createElement('script');
            i.src = '/static/elements/my-element.js';
            document.body.appendChild(i);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(c);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(e);
}
```

This works, but is obviously extremely inefficient (especially on slow/high latency networks) and also looks very noisy. Before trying to support Firefox I could simply do:

```
<script src="/static/elements/my-element.js"></script>
```

Now I have this abomination above. There has to be a better way, but I can't seem to find one.

How can I make sure that the customElement and ShadyCSS polyfills run before `my-element.js` without delaying the downloads that much? Any pointers are highly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
For now I'm using another approach which I will add here. I don't think it's perfect, but seems to be better than my first approach or forcing everyone to download the polyfills regardless of whether or not they need them.

```
function insertScript(url, downloadAsync) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    script.async = downloadAsync;
    script.src = url;
    return script;
}

function downloadAsync(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const script = insertScript(url, 'true');
        script.onload = resolve;
        script.onerror = reject;
    });
}

var deps = [];
if (!('customElements' in window)) {
    deps.push(downloadAsync('/url/of/polyfill.js'));
    // if you need more than 1 polyfill add more deps.push
}

Promise.all(deps).then(() => {
    insertScript('/static/elements/my-element.js');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The recommended way is to always [load the complete polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#how-to-use) (82 ko only).

```
<script src="/path/to/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<script src="/static/elements/my-element.js"></script>
```

Since scripts loading is synchronous the polyfill and custom elements will be loaded in the right order.

If you want to support only Firefox and Edge, you can replace *webcomponents-lite.js* by *webcomponents-sd-ce.js* (64 ko) but you will gain only a few millisecond in most cases.

---

Alternately, and for very bad networks, you can [use the *webcomponents-loader.js*](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#webcomponents-loaderjs) (4 ko) that will perform the feature detection and loading for you.

You can minify it too, or even better, insert its content directly in your main page to save one request round-trip delay.

Comment: Forcing 82kb / 64kb to everyone, regardless if they need it or not, is something I'd rather not do. I tried using the `webcomponents-loader.js`, but my custom element seems to run before the actual polyfill got run (dynamically loaded scripts seem to be run async?).

Comment: Yes it's asynchronous so you should wait for the WebComponentsReady event as explained in the link